# How to downgrade Linux kernel

Tags: linux, system-restore, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I have a Linux machine running RHEL3.8 with kernel release `2.4.21-66.ELsmp`.

How can I downgrade the Linux kernel to `2.4.21-47.ELsmp`?

Second:
About the last kernel upgrade, can we find logs somewhere regarding the last upgrade? ,

- remark - /var/log/message not mentioned the last upgrade (kernel upgrade was before 1/2 year)

Comment: welcome to 21st Century ;)

Comment: @Michał Šrajer yes I agree I have old Linux machine with application , but I need to downgrade because after upgrade machine make troubles , Please advice if it's possible? and if its true then how ?

Comment: [here](http://www.unix.com/red-hat/163712-downgrade-kernel-version-yum.html) you can have a good solution

Comment: you mean by this command I can downgrade ? yum install kernel-2.6.x.x.x.x.x , any way I have not idea how to edit grub.conf ? , I see also they talk about the solution but finnaly they have problem as No package kernel-2.6.12 available!!!!!

Comment: Need to consider migrating this question to serverfault or Unix & Linux forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not idea how to edit grub.conf ?

For this

First create a backup of your `/boot/grub/grub.conf` file

Your all kernel files will be present under `/boot`

```
[root@localhost boot]# ls -l vmlinuz-2.6.32-2*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 3811616 Dec  6  2011 vmlinuz-2.6.32-220.el6.i686
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 3815136 Dec 19 10:22 vmlinuz-2.6.32-279.19.1.el6.i686
```

These are the initrd images

```
[root@localhost boot]# ls -l symvers-2.6.32-2*
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 168173 Dec  6  2011 symvers-2.6.32-220.el6.i686.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 175982 Dec 19 10:22 symvers-2.6.32-279.19.1.el6.i686.gz
```

Now open your grub.conf file

Just copy your previous kernel lines that means title,root,kernel,initrd, and paste it below and change the kernel version numbers.

You can refer the sample file here

```
title CentOS (2.6.32-279.19.1.el6.i686)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-279.19.1.el6.i686 ro root=UUID=2d15d825-80de-4d2d-beae-23140c053e99 rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_LVM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD quiet SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 rhgb crashkernel=auto  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM
        initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-279.19.1.el6.i686.img
```

```
title CentOS (2.6.32-220.el6.i686)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-220.el6.i686 ro root=UUID=2d15d825-80de-4d2d-beae-23140c053e99 rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_LVM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD quiet SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 rhgb crashkernel=auto  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM
        initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-220.el6.i686.img
```

Comment: before the grub.conf how to run the yum install ...? ( can you please add this in to your answer , not sure if I need to set this ? " yum install kernel-2.4.21-47" ????

Comment: About the previous grub.conf ( or the old grub.conf ) this file should be backup before the upgrade ( upgrade was before 1/2 year ), I hope I will find this old file but what the solution if no grub.conf backup ?

Comment: backup your present grub.conf file. if you miss configure your grub.conf file then your system wont boot at all. At that time you can rescue your system by using your backup file. or you can install a new grub by using `grub-install /dev/sda` command `sda` or `hda` it depends on your hard disk. for doing this you need to go to rescue mode.

Comment: what about the - yum install kernel-2.4.21-47" ???? ( how to create the right syntax ?

Comment: I'm working on that, If I got the answer then I will post here.

Comment: ok great - thx so mutch ,

Comment: did you find something ?